# Error executing SQL commands to create table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am using Mysql-query-browser(mysql gui from mysql.com) to create a table.

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`mytable` (
`client` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
`url` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
`keywords` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

But I keep getting the following error message:

```
Error executing SQL commands to create table.

  MySQL Error Nr. 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
  check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
 'NOT NULL,`description` VARCHAR NOT NULL,`url` VARCHAR NOT NULL,`keywo' at line 4
```

If any one know How to fix it? 
Please Help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you define a column as `varchar` you have to add the maximum length for an entry to that column (see [MySQL docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)). So in your example that could result in the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`mytable` (
`client` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`url` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`keywords` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Note that you have to add this for all three occurrences of `varchar` in your statement.

Comment: When I set The value it Will give error like this Error executing SQL commands to create table.
MySQL Error Nr. 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar  DEFAULT 15,
  `status` varchar  DEFAU' at line 2

Comment: @abhishek It works fine for me, see, e.g., here at this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdb85/1/0). Also the column names in your error point to a different table as in your example there is no "name" or "status".

Answer (score 0):

You must specify length for VARCHAR TYPE

```
   CREATE TABLE `test_model`.`mytable` (
    `client` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `url` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `keywords` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
    )
    ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the size of the varchar should do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`mytable` (
`client` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`url` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`keywords` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM;
```